# Passing Selected Datatable rows to Flow Collection inside of a screen flow

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, visual-workflow

I'm really lost with this one. First time i've tried anything similar. I want my user to see a datatable of records that is provided by the flow, select which ones they want to act on, and then pass those selected records back to the flow as a collection variable. I can display the data fine, but when I select the rows and continue, nothing is getting updated.

Would love some help on this. Do I need a button instead of using onrowaction? A separate property maybe, rather than trying to change the records one?

Appreciate it!

```
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>52.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
        <target>lightning__AppPage</target>
        <target>lightning__FlowScreen</target>
    </targets>
    <targetConfigs>
        <targetConfig targets="lightning__FlowScreen">
            <propertyType extends="SObject" name="T" label="Select SObject"/>
            <property name="records" type="{T[]}" label="Records" />
        </targetConfig>
    </targetConfigs>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

```
 @api records = [];
    @api selected;
    @api fieldColumns = [
        {label: 'Course Name', fieldName: 'Course_Offering_Name__c'},
        {label: 'Course Status', fieldName: 'Status__c'},
        {label: 'Semester', fieldName: 'Term_Registration_Name__c'}
    ];
   

    connectedCallback() {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(this.records));
    }
    // @api options = [
    //     {value: '1', label:'Course_Offering_Name__c'}
    // ]
    handleRowSelection(event) {
       this.records = event.detail.selectedRows;
        console.log(selectedRows);
        const attributeChangeEvent = FlowAttributeChangeEvent(
            'records',
            this.records
        );
        this.dispatchEvent(attributeChangeEvent);
    }
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>52.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
        <target>lightning__AppPage</target>
        <target>lightning__FlowScreen</target>
    </targets>
    <targetConfigs>
        <targetConfig targets="lightning__FlowScreen">
            <propertyType extends="SObject" name="T" label="Select SObject"/>
            <property name="records" type="{T[]}" label="Records" />
        </targetConfig>
    </targetConfigs>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flow events are proper objects, which means you have to construct them. You do this with the `new` operator.

```
const attributeChangeEvent = new FlowAttributeChangeEvent(
    'records',
    this.records
);
```

Comment: Aaaaah, I'm so silly. Thanks again for your help. You've answered so many of my questions already.